# Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis using python

Tags: python, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I am working on Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis.In this project we collected data from twitter. After collecting data we performed text cleaning methods and create a corpus. After that we used this corpus to find the aspects using noun_phrases in python.It gives me the list of noun phrases. From this list i want to select only those aspects which contain only two words. How can i do that?

Here is my code and generated output:

```
from textblob import Word
comments = TextBlob(' '.join(corpus))
comments.noun_phrases
cleaned = list()
for phrase in comments.noun_phrases:
    count = 0
    for w in phrase.split():
        # Count the number of small words and words without an English definition
        if len(w) <= 2 or (not Word(w).definitions):
            count += 1
    # Only if the 'nonsensical' or short words DO NOT make up more than 40% (arbitrary) of the phrase add
    # it to the cleaned list, effectively pruning the ones not added.
    if count < len(phrase.split())*0.4:
        cleaned.append(phrase)       
print("After compactness pruning:\nFeature Size:")
print(cleaned)
```

Output:
['worth free food k retweet pleas', 'specif waiter job', 'red blend', 'old idea suddenli', 'global focus', 'local issu lot', 'africa food', 'food truck', 'space avail netbal woman footbal amp squash', 'week world cup', 'minor sign confess', 'french fri coupl day', 'great stuff ban plastic straw serv local produc ta xe x xa b differ food home food school home', 'stale croissant', 'thing time', 'great time saver bc', 'clean chop alreadi', 'fake news unit alreadi', 'sure food amp cosmet', 'long food', 'dog china american', 'trade china till', 'warm color', 'yellow orang', 'fast food restaur', 'yellow orang', 'emerg food parcel', 'junk food label parti size', 'share water check systemsthink', 'earth food', 'care chihuahua yappi requir food sleep', 'new cloth', 'dose moron', 'afraid poor rise peopl', 'friend feed', 'wrong shit', 'good guy', 'good bad guy', 'food pension livelihood', 'food fur babi fun stay']

From this we want to select only those noun phrases which contain only two words such as 'red blend','food truck','stale croissant',etc. How can i do that?

Comment: the TLDR is, looping over noun_phrases, how do i find which phrases only have 2 words?

Answer (score 0):

look for items in the list which only have one occurrence of a space

Edit: updated to list comprehension for brevity and speed:

```
word_list = [phrase for phrase in a if phrase.count(' ') == 1]
```

Timing comparison:

```
startTime = time.time()

for i in range(1000000):
    word_list = []
    for phrase in comments.noun_phrases:
        if phrase.count(' ') == 1:
            word_list.append(phrase)

print(time.time() - startTime)
9.743234395980835

startTime = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    word_list = [phrase for phrase in comments.noun_phrases if len(phrase.split(" ")) == 2]

print(time.time() - startTime)
14.307061433792114

startTime = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    word_list = [phrase for phrase in comments.noun_phrases if phrase.count(' ') == 1]

print(time.time() - startTime)
7.5759406089782715
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list, denoted by comments.noun_phrases, and you are trying to find the phrases which only have 2 words in it.

```
word_list = [phrase for phrase in comments.noun_phrases if len(phrase.split(" ")) == 2]
```

If you want speed though, you would likely prefer the count method for the if case.

```
word_list = [phrase for phrase in comments.noun_phrases if phrase.count(" ") == 1]
```

this would, given a list of noun phrases, would return you a list where it would contain only 2 words.  This does not account for cleaning etc, as you stated in your question you have a list of cleaned phrases.

Comment: nice list comprehension, applied it using `phrase.count(' ') == 1` and it sped up my loop significantly

Comment: Count is better, it scans the list once, and doesnt spend time allocating space and creating arrays.  Ideally, yes that is the correct one. Ill modify my answer.